# MPMoviePlayerViewController gets dissmiss when app goes background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I press on Home Button, or switch to another app, while `MPMoviePlayerViewController` on screen, and open app again it shows `UIViewController` who sent
`moviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:`.

How can I just pause my video like youtube app?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the project's plist.The option is "Application does not run in background",May  this is set to YES.This may be one reason

Comment: I added this option and set it to NO, but it didn't help, unfortunatly